# If $A > 0, |x| < \sqrt{A}$ prove that $\frac{1}{2}\left|x + A\frac{1}{x}\right| > \sqrt{A}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

If $A > 0, |x| < \sqrt{A}$ prove that $\frac{1}{2}\left|x + A\frac{1}{x}\right| > \sqrt{A}$

My work:

\begin{align*}
  |x| <& \sqrt{A} \\
  \frac{1}{|x|} >& \frac{1}{\sqrt{A}} \\
  A\frac{1}{|x|} >& \sqrt{A} \\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  \frac{1}{2}\left|x + A\frac{1}{x}\right| &\le \frac{1}{2} \left(|x| + A \frac{1}{|x|}\right)\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Do you know the $AM-GM$ inequality?

Comment: No, but reading it now.

Comment: For $a\ge 0$, and $b\ge 0$, we have $(\sqrt a - \sqrt b)^2\ge0\;\;\Rightarrow a+b\ge 2\sqrt{ab}$

Answer (score 0):

squaring the given inequality we get $$\frac{1}{4}\left(x^2+\frac{A^2}{x^2}+2A\right)\geq 4A$$and this is equivalent to $$\left(x-\frac{A}{x}\right)^2\geq 0$$
since $$|x|<\sqrt{A}$$ it must be $$A>0$$